# Why can't concrete members be overridden with abstract ones in scala?

Tags: scala, oop, overriding

For instance, in the following code:

```
class Animal
class Dog extends Animal
trait Base {
  def a: Animal = new Dog
}
trait Deri extends Base {
  override val a: Dog
}
```

The following error is given:

> error: overriding value a in trait Deri of type Dog;  method a in
>   trait Base of type => Animal needs to be a stable, immutable value; 
>   (Note that value a in trait Deri of type Dog is abstract,   and is
>   therefore overridden by concrete method a in trait Base of type =>
>   Animal)

I want to know, since I have explicitly modified `a` in `Deri` with `override`, while does Scala choose to do the other way around(overriding `a` in `Deri` with that in `Base` as indicated in error msg)?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your question. `Deri` is attempting to override `Base`, but fails since `Base` *already provides* a base implementation, while `Deri` attempts to make it abstract again.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov yes, but in `Deri`, a is of type `Dog` instead of `Animal`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Scala Spec](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/05-classes-and-objects.html#class-members), a concrete definition always overrides an abstract definition.

> This definition also determines the overriding relationships between
>   matching members of a class C and its parents. **First, a concrete**
>   **definition always overrides an abstract definition.** Second, for
>   definitions M and M' which are both concrete or both abstract, M
>   overrides M′ if M appears in a class that precedes (in the
>   linearization of C) the class in which M′ is defined.

So, to make it compiled, you have to make sure the abstract method is overridable by the concrete one. Change Deri:

```
trait Deri extends Base { override def a:Animal }
```

or change Base

```
trait Base { val a: Dog = new Dog }
```