# How to force subclasses to override an inherited method with a more specific return type

Tags: scala, inheritance, overriding

Consider this example:

```
trait SpecialIntIterable extends Iterable[Int] {

  override def iterator: Iterator[Int] = ??? // implementation not relevant

  override def tail : SpecialIntIterable

  // plus some more methods...

}

class MyPrimeIterable extends SpecialIntIterable {

  override def tail : SpecialIntIterable = ??? // implementation not relevant

}
```

I'm trying to force all subclasses of `SpecialIntIterable` to implement `tail` so it returns a `SpecialIntIterable` again. Is this possible?

Currently I'm getting the following compiler error:

```
overriding method tail in trait SpecialIntIterable of type => de.cointrade.trader.SpecialIntIterable;     
method tail in trait TraversableLike of type => Iterable[Int] has incompatible type;
(Note that method tail in trait SpecialIntIterable of type => de.cointrade.trader.SpecialIntIterable is abstract,
and is therefore overridden by concrete method tail in trait TraversableLike of type => Iterable[Int])
trait SpecialIntIterable extends Iterable[Int] {
```

**Edit:** One solution I found is to introduce an abstract helper method (for instance called `rest`) in `SpecialIntIterable` and let `tail` delegate to it. However, I'd like to know if it is possible without an extra member.

Comment: ...maybe I misunderstand the question, because I don't understand "more specific than *what*?"

Comment: @AndreyTyukin, I meant more specific than `Iterable[Int]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [Architecture of Scala Collections](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/architecture-of-scala-collections.html) this is called "same-result-type principle". In the collection libraries, this is achieved by template classes with names ending with `Like`, occasionally mixed with some F-bound polymorphism. Essentially, if you want an interface that looks somehow like this

```
trait Foo {
  def makeResult: Foo // how enforce same-result-type ?
}
```

but you want to enforce that instead of `Foo` all implementing subclasses return something of their own type, you modify `Foo` as follows:

```
trait FooLike[+Repr] {
  def makeResult: Repr
}
```

and then implement subclasses as

```
class Bar extends FooLike[Bar] {
  def makeResult: Bar = ??? // now `Bar` is enforced as return type
}
```

In your case, you might try something like this:

```
import scala.collection.IterableLike
import scala.collection.mutable.Builder

trait SpecialIntIterableLike[+Repr] extends IterableLike[Int, Repr]

abstract class SpecialIntIterable 
  extends Iterable[Int] 
  with SpecialIntIterableLike[SpecialIntIterable] {

  override def newBuilder: Builder[Int, SpecialIntIterable] = ???
}

class MyPrimeIterable extends SpecialIntIterable with SpecialIntIterableLike[MyPrimeIterable] {
  def iterator: Iterator[Int] = ???
  override def tail : MyPrimeIterable = ???                    // must override, otherwise compile-time errors
  override def newBuilder: Builder[Int, MyPrimeIterable] = ??? // must override, otherwise compile-time errors
}
```

Notice where the `newBuilder`-method has to be overridden to resolve conflicts (this is mentioned in the above linked document).

---

**EDIT**

Even if your `MyPrimeIterable` chooses not to extend `SpecialIntIterableLike`, it still *must* implement a `tail` that returns at least a `SpecialIntIterable`:

```
class MyOtherIterable extends SpecialIntIterable {
  def iterator: Iterator[Int] = ???
  override def newBuilder: Builder[Int, SpecialIntIterable] = ???
  // def tail: Iterable[Int] = List(0) // won't compile
}
```

If we try to loosen the return type of `tail`, it won't compile, because a `SpecialIntIterable` extends `SpecialIntIterableLike[SpecialIntIterable]`.

This is similar to extending for example `IndexedSeq[X]`: you can choose not to implement `IndexedSeqLike[X, MyType]`, so the "same-result-type"-property will deteriorate a little bit, but the result type of `tail` will *still be at least `IndexedSeq[X]`*, not `Iterable[X]` or something weaker than `IndexedSeq[X]`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! However, it seems it does not really solve my problem. `MyPrimeIterable` can still decide not to implement tail or implement it with a more general return type. By the way, I'm not requiring that the return type is the same (i.e., `MyPrimeIterable`), only `SpecialIntIterable` that is abstract.

Comment: In the above example, it's not possible for `MyPrimeIterable` to implement `tail` that is not `SpecialIntIterable`. It can drop the `SpecialIntIterable[MyPrimeIterable]`, but it cannot drop the requirement that `tail` must return at least a `SpecialIntIterable`. Or am I missing something? Updated my answer to address specifically the bounds of the `tail` return type.

Comment: I think I got it now: if `MyOtherIterable` does not override `tail` at all, it will automatically get the correct type `SpecialIntIterable`. I was confused because I could comment the `def tail...` line and it still compiled.

Comment: So there is no direct way to "undefine" a method of a super class to force subclasses to reimplement it? Or at least force them to implement it with a more specific return type than the return type of the super implementation?

Comment: @lex82 Ah, so you wanted to override a concrete implementation in a supertrait by an abstract implementation in the extending trait? Unfortunately, that's [not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40172423/why-cant-concrete-members-be-overridden-with-abstract-ones-in-scala). I think this has something to do with how the correct method implementation is resolved in the chain of linearized traits: it simply walks the linearized chain bottom up, and picks the first method that is implemented. There seems to be no way to "abstractly re-shadow" an already implemented method.

Comment: Thanks, now I got it. I should have generalized and simplified my example further.